# Generating coverage report for e2e testing

Tags: angularjs, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing, istanbul

I've created an Angular 2 Typescript application. I'm using Protractor for running e2e test cases. I need to generated coverage report for e2e test cases using Istanbul or any other tool available.
I cannot use grunt-protractor-coverage. Also, protractor-istanbul-plugin is abandoned now and cannot be used for production level applications.
Is there any other tool available for generating coverage report for e2e test cases?